# Different screen resolution, same size screens, playing same video on both the screens

Tags: video, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Let's assume i have *screen1* with resolution `1080*1920` and *screen2* with resolution `720*1280`. The size of both screens are 15".

Now I am playing a video with resolution `360*480` on *screen1* and *screen2*.

Which one should look better?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer assumes all other things are the same.  Sometimes higher resolutions get processed slower, and you might appreciate a faster frame rate more than a higher resolution.  Also, when hardware specifications state that a resolution like 1080x1920 is supported, that doesn't necessarily mean that the hardware is as high of quality.  A crisp image may be better than a blurry image.  So my answer is just addressing the differences in resolution, and doesn't go into details about the other differences that may exist between your screens.  (Namely, I didn't provide a detailed answer about that because you didn't provide any details about the screens.)  So, this answer focuses on just the impact of the resolution.

That said, here's my short answer, followed by the explanation.

The 1080x1920 one should look nicer.  Although, the difference may be imperceptible.

- Reason number one: a nice multiple

1080 is 360 times 3
720 is 360 times 2
1920 is 480 x 4
1280 is 480 x 2-and-two-thirds (2.333ish)

a factor of 3x4 is good clean math.  For every pixel in the video, scale up to 3 or 4 pixels.  A factor of 2.333 is not so clean.  Every pixel in the video gets turned into 2 horizontal pixels, and probably 3 vertical pixels but sometimes 2 vertical pixels.  That may cause things to be less perfect.

(Note: I'm taking you at your word, that the video resolutions are 720x1280 and 1080x1920.  However, I think resolutions of 1280x720 and 1920x1080 sound far more common.  Usually the length of a horizontal row gets mentioned first.  If the first number you did mention was the number of pixels in each vertical column, them the logic of my argument still applies.  You would just need to flip the words "vertical" and "horizontal" as appropriate.)

- Reason 2 : Video improvement technologies

Concepts like "upscaling" and "anti-aliasing" and so forth mean that when a small object becomes bigger, advanced video processing techniques may try to smooth out the image so it doesn't look quite so jagged.  If your software does any such thing, then the resulting image may actually look more like a 1080x1920 image than a 720x1280.  In general, more pixels represent higher quality, and look better.

(Of course, this second reason will have no impact at all if your software doesn't actually produce any sort of video-altering techniques other than simple scaling by duplicating pixels as needed.)

Comment: "more pixels represent higher quality" only if the image has been rendered at that resolution. This video is not. 3x scaling is massive (quality loss), the aspect ratios of both screens are different (incorrect aspect=quality loss) , non-mulitples of 2=quality loss (quantization). MPEG artifacts are enlarged (quality loss). The OP doesn't say if he means full screen. Anti-aliasing is, in essence, a blur algorithm (quality loss). Unscaled the lower resolution screen will have a larger apparent size, and the higher resolution screen will appear sharper because the pixels are packed more densely.

Comment: @Yorik : Although I'd often think that blurring sharp images could be a quality loss, in the case of anti-aliasing, it means that the computer figures out which jaggedness of sharp images is undesirable.  So blurring is making the results to be closer to the desired reality, looking more accurate.  Isn't that a gain, not a loss?  (Otherwise, why would it even be done?)  As for MPEG artifacts growing, how is that a quality loss? For instance, if I have a 1 inch by 1 inch white box that doesn't belong, how is it a loss if the identical unwanted white box, on the larger screen, has more pixels?

Comment: Because scaling means averaging and so you are adding the average of two artifacts, and including the result, many parts of this process are then quantized (e.g. rounded to an integer) because there is no such thing as half a pixel.

Comment: If i say that the quality of picture(because of repeating same pixels ) or video decreases if we magnify it. If it is correct?? then we can say that we need to magnify the picture more to show it on high resolution screen than to low resolution screen. That means the video should look better in low resolution screen than in high resolution screen. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: for discussion sake...
we can take two screen of same size.
scr1 with resolution 12*18
scr2 with resolution 8*12
and original image with resolution 4*6.
so to show the image on scr1, magnification will be 3
and to show the image on scr1, magnification will be 2.
doesn't that mean the picture will look better on scr2 than on scr1